# How to I change this css psuedo button in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, pseudo-class

I found this really nice checkbox button style (link below) and have been trying to turn it on and off using jQuery. I haven't used many pseudo-classes before, normally I just add an 'active' class.

https://proto.io/freebies/onoff/

I need the button to be turned ON or OFF upon page load based on server response, but I can't seem to manipulate the CSS without breaking it. How am I meant to activate/deactivate this button?

```css
.onoffswitch {
  position: relative;
  width: 90px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
  display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before,
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
  content: "ON";
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #34A7C1;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  content: "OFF";
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #999999;
  text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  margin: 6px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 56px;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="onoffswitch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
  <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't add and remove pseudo classes.  They're just based on the state of the element.

Comment: You want to toggle the element programmatically? The visual state of the toggle is determined by the `checked` state of the input, so changing the `checked` state will change how the toggle looks.

Comment: as @showdev says the state of the css button is based on the state of the checkbox. Just set the checkbox to checked=true and the css button should reflect this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you programmatically want to change the state, don't fiddle with CSS classes,

Just a oneliner by use of jQuery:

```
 $('#myonoffswitch').attr('checked', false); // turn off
 $('#myonoffswitch').attr('checked', true); // turn on
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5eoujsm4/

animated update: http://jsfiddle.net/5eoujsm4/1/

Comment: Thanks..can you explain how the :before and :after event is trigged within the example?

Comment: These are no events. Events are procedural, `:before` and `:after` are CSS pseudo classes controlling the layout of the given element by adding some static content.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove the `:before` or `:after` selectors using javascript, because those are CSS rules that you've made.

Instead, create two separate classes for what you want:

```
.start-state:before {
    ...
}
.end-state:before {
    ...
}
```

and then change your javascript to:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
      $('.onoffswitch-inner').addClass('end-state').removeClass('start-state');
}
```

Alternatively, you could add a default `:before` state to your `.onoffswitch-inner` CSS rule, and then *overwrite it* by adding an `.onoffswitch-inner.active:before` rule.

This will let you do `$('.onoffswitch-inner').toggleClass('active');`.

Comment: If you're going to down vote at least leave a comment.

Comment: Given how much the asker changed his question with his edits, I don't know if this even answers his question anymore. Thanks for equaling it out though @Mike.

Comment: Wasn't me that downvoted, but it does seem a bit over-complicated considering all they have to do is change that state of the input. As Jonathan says, it's confusing to keep up with constant edits by the OP.

Comment: Yep. At the time I wrote my answer, the question was "how do I switch on/off CSS pseudo elements". This is completely different now. Is it proper etiquette to just delete my answer at this point?

Comment: yeah showdev kinda edited my question quite a bit...but its good to keep your answer up, its an alternative method to learn from...thanks